# How to merge tables without duplicates and maintain foreign references?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, etl, data-warehouse

I'm creating a data warehouse for a healthcare company. They have separate databases for different hospitals which contain tables on patients,their insurance,etc and PK is unique only within one hospital DB. When merged, I'm supposed to create a Master Patient Table, a Master Insurance Company table,etc that combines duplicate data into one record(eg. by comparing name and SSN fields for patients).

Any suggestions on how to do this merge, and create correct FK references in the new tables? A record in the Patient table needs to have a correct reference to an insurance company in the Insurance table. Any help or general pointers is appreciated!

Comment: If your (external) keys can be trusted: trust them. If they cannot: use a surrogate keya and a datavault-like method to resolve equivalence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the data from the first hospital (H1) into the warehouse. Then, move in the patient data from the second hospital (H2):

```
insert into P1.Patients( pid, ... )
select P2.pid, P2.this, P2.that, ...
from   H2.Patients P2
left join H1.Patients P1
    on P1.ssn = P2.ssn
where P1.pid is null;
```

Now you have added the P2 patients that were not already in the P1 patient table but retained the P1 patient ids of those already there. (You may have to handle collisions.) Then join the H2 insurance table with the H2 patient table to get the SSN joining with H1 patient table to get the H1.PatientID (pid).

```
insert into H1.Insurance( pid, ...)
select P1.pid, I2.this, I2.that,... -- To get H1's pid for H2's patients...
from   H2.Insurance I2    -- Join the 2nd hospital's insurance table
join   H2.Patients P2     -- ...with its patient table
    on P2.pid = I2.pid    -- ...based on its existing patient ID value.
join   H1.Patients P1     -- Now you can join with first hospitals patient table
    on P1.ssn = P2.ssn    -- ...using SSN from 2nd hospital's patient table
where  anything_else;
```

Repeat for other tables, using P1.pid to replace all uses of P2.pid.

Comment: I cannot make sense of this line "Then join the H2 insurance table with the H2 patient table to get the SSN joining with H1 patient table to get the H1.PatientID (pid)." Could you explain a bit more? Thanks

Comment: I already provided a sample to illustrate but I've added some comments to make it even more clear (I hope). For those patients that are in both databases, insert the data from the 2nd hospital's database into the 1st hospital's database but using the patient id of the 1st hospital. The 2nd hospital's id is simply left behind, so to speak. This performs a merge of patient data.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer just seems horribly inefficient. Instead of doing so many joins I would have a SELECT statement FROM H1.P P1 and H2.P P2 where P1.SSN==P2.SSN and insert this into H1. Then have a select for Insurance FK,Guarantor FK and whatever else you have on this result and left join it to this table. Do something similar for Insurance tables. Then select records where Insurance ID matches Insurance FK in patient and update them with new surrogate keys..

Although I would like someone with more experience taking on this question as well..